# How do I start a .exe with a json string as parameter correctly?

Tags: c#, json, parameters, process

The below is just an example of the functionality.

I have a model like this:

```
public class StartParams
{
    public string ParameterOne { get; set; }
    public string ParameterTwo { get; set; }
    public string ParameterThree { get; set; }
}
```

From a WPF app. I am serializing it as JSON like this:

```
var startParams = new StartParams
{
    ParameterOne = "parameterOne",
    ParameterTwo = "parameterTwo",
    ParameterThree = "parameterThree"
};

var jsonStartParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(startParams);
```

Then I'm launching a .exe file with the JSON string as a parameter.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = jsonStartParams,
    FileName = "C:\\Folder\\File.exe"
};

Process.Start(info);
```

In **File.exe** I have a Task which takes a string:

```
public static async Task DoSomething(string jsonStartParams)
{
    var startParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StartParams>(jsonStartParams);
```

When debugging, I can call the static Main method in File.exe like this:

```
string[] parameters = {jsonStartParams};
File.Program.Main(parameters);
```

This works like a charm, but as soon as I call the .exe file with Process.Start, with the JSON string parameter, it fails with

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

at the first prop in the JSON object.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to do that. It's very difficult to escape a Windows command string properly. The answer below is not going to help. Instead, save the JSON string to a TEMP file and use the filename as a parameter - or pipe it into the .exe via stdin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes in jsonStartParams are making the argument separated into multiple arguments. Try escaping the quotes like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = "\"" + jsonStartParams.Replace("\"",  "\\\"") + "\"",
    FileName = "C:\\Folder\\File.exe"
};
```

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to escape the JSON string

something like this

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
};

var jsonStartParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(startParams, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried that. Did not solve the problem.

Comment: Not recommended. Json can be full of special characters with meaning, such as &  "  |  >  <  and more. For a command line parameter, all these need to be escaped in a special way. Just escaping quotes won't fix things reliably. Escaping into HTML is a surefire way to add & to the parameters which is just as bad.