# Passing JSON to EXE file yields "newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value"

Tags: c#, json

I have an exe file which gets started with a parameter by another method.

My exe file's main method is in my `program` class which looks like this:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        Application.Run(new PAMain(args[0])); //args[0] is the parameter

    }
```

I get the sent parameter by calling args[0], which is the JSON data.

Notice the other class `new PAMain` where I pass this args[0] to its constructor which looks like this:

```
    public PAMain(string json)
    {
        InitializeComponent();       

        SetJsonData(json);          

    }
```

The `SetJsonData()` method deserializes the json string, which is where the error happens, the`SetJsonData()` method looks like this:

```
string jsonData;
private AsanaRootData root = new AsanaRootData();

public string SetJsonData(string json)
{
   this.jsonData = json;          

   root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AsanaRootData>(jsonData);  //The error happens here          

   return json;
}
```

The error happens at `"root =..."`.
The error I get is `newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value ... at line ...`

If I call the `SetJsonData()` method on the original JSON data and not the exe passed one, everything works. So I think that the error itself is that maybe after passing the JSON data to the exe file and calling args[0] the data is not JSON anymore?

Here is the error popup in my GUI:

[image]

The error happens after `assignee_status:` at the symbol `l` in the word `later`

Comment: "maybe after passing the JSON data to the exe file and calling args[0] the data is not JSON anymore?" The best way to find out is to debug the data received in args. You'll most likely find that the the string is transformed by the shell command line. Does it have spaces? if so are you passing the full json string within quotes making sure any quotes of the same type inside the string are escaped?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. If you pas an invalid json string, you'll get an exception. The exception tells you *where* to find the problem too `at line ...`. The code you posted doesn't help. Either post the file that causes the problem or debug your application and check what's passed to it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the OP says when the _same_ string is assigned to a variable in the code, it works. Only having problem passing the string from command line.

Comment: Post the *full* exception, not just parts of it. As you can see from the message you posted it tells you what was wrong and where the error occured

Comment: @marekful which means it's not the same string. The exception shows exactly where the error occured but the OP didn't post that part

Comment: @marekful I'd guess the OP tried to pass the same string without proper escaping in the second case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well, are you talking about which point in (his) time?

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AsanaRootData>(jsonData?.ToString());`

Comment: `If I call the SetJsonData() method on the original JSON data and not the exe passed one, everything works` - out of plain curiosity: you did not possibly call the method on the original full json string and then passed the *path* to the original json to the exe instead?

Comment: I haven't passed any path no, the SetJsonData() should get the full JSON data yes and then Convert it.

Comment: I have not escaped anything anywhere

Comment: I have uploaded the error popup

Answer (score 0):

The problem was escaping, I solved it by starting the exe file up this way instead

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
   Arguments = "\"" + jsonData.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"",
   FileName = "path"
}; 

Process.Start(info);
```

I found it here: [How do I start a .exe with a json string as parameter correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848338/how-do-i-start-a-exe-with-a-json-string-as-parameter-correctly)